# Suspense is not loading content after render reactjs

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I am using **code-splitting** lazy load concept of reactjs. But `<Suspense>` is not seems to work for me because it's not showing me the fallback loading message and directly loading the code on render inside it.

I am running react app in my local dev enviroment and not using it's production version. Below is the code I am using.

```
import React,{ lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

class Homepage extends React.Component{
render(){
   return(
     <div>
       <Suspense fallback={<h2>Products are loading...</h2>}>
          // products display code
       </Suspense>
     </div>
   );
}
```

Here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bouman-egx93

Comment: where is your lazy import component? you need to something import like lazy https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html  `const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));`

Comment: You have to import the components inside suspense through lazy

Comment: @prasanth, Can't I put manual code inside it?

Comment: why what is the problem ?post working code on https://codesandbox.io/s/new and share with me

Comment: It's not working for the component also.

Comment: @prasanth, Have a look now. I have updated the code with lazy loading.

Comment: @alex where? please share the link

Comment: @prasanth, https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bouman-egx93

Comment: @prasanth, So, Did you got what's the problem?

Comment: Better develop you app.After get more load you will see the loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lazy import your Homepage component in your App.js file(where you make routing) and Lazy import your Product component like this;

**App.js**

```js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const HomePage = lazy(() => import('./pages/home/HomePage'))

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Suspense fallback={<h2>Loading...</h2>}>
              <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
            </Suspense>
          </Switch>
       </BrowserRouter>
      )
  }

}
export default App
```

Lazy load Products component, setTimeout to 0, 1000 is just for debugging

**HomePage.js**

```js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'

const Products = React.lazy(() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(
    () => import(".../components/products/Products")
  );
});


export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<h2>Products are loading...</h2>}>
        <Products />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have to lazy load the products list inside the homepage component.

Comment: Once you are in the homepage component, you want to lazy load the products right?

Comment: okey, then you need to also lazy import your Products component inside Homepage, I extended the answer

Comment: It's not working, Have a look at the Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bouman-egx93

Comment: So, Did you got what's the problem?

Comment: I understand, let me take a look

Comment: Can you try again with the last component? It actually works but I think it is just too fast, if you make timeout from 1000 to 0

Comment: so how can I specify the timeout? Actually I tried by adding placeholder. But with placeholder component is not rendering.

Comment: setTimeout(resolve, 1000)) to setTimeout(resolve, 0))

Comment: I mean where should I add this?

Comment: Add it to your HomePage component, inside import your Products component, I extended my answer take a look :)

Comment: Yes, It's working now :). But can you please let me know so what's the benifit of lazy loading if it's too fast?

Comment: I think you should just lazy load the components if for example you are getting products from an external api and it will take time to render the component, but if it is a component that just returns static html then there is no need to use lazy loading